# force refreshing formula in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a lot of sheets and lot of formula (named as MATRIX) . I create a new empty spreadsheet (named as NEW_MATRIX). I copied 2 sheets from MATRIX to NEW_MATRIX. The way I copied them is by right click the sheet then select ‘copy to’ and select existing spreadsheet (NEW_MATRIX). The 2 sheets I copied are SETTING and SHOTS. The SHOTS  has a lot of formula that linked to SETTING and vice versa. For example in SHOTS , I have formulas such as : SETTING!B2  or SETTING!C3 etc.

After I copied the sheets, I open the NEW_MATRIX and found the new copied sheets as ‘copy of SETTING’ and ‘copy of SHOTS’ . By default the name of the copied sheets is started with ‘copy of’ . This make all the formula broken because It can’t find the SETTING and SHOTS sheet. For example : the formula such as SETTING!B2 has error ‘unresolved sheet name SETTING’

I renamed those sheets by removing the word ‘copy of ‘ so now both the sheets are having the correct name ‘SETTING’ and ‘SHOTS’ but still the error exist because it won’t updated or refreshed automatically. I can fix all those #REF! by select the cell containing the formula and simply press ENTER.

But the problem I got really a lot of broken #REF! all over the place, so I have to manually click/select it then press ENTER for every single formula.

Is there any other way to refresh it automatically ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have several cells with **#REF! (Unresolved sheet name)** error like in the following screenshot:

[image]

You can force all the formulas to refresh by opening the 'Find and replace' tool (<kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Find and replace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and fill the fields as follows:

- **Find**: `=`
- **Replace with**: `=`
- **Search**: `This sheet`
- **Also search within formulas**: `✔`

[image]

Then click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd> and <kbd>Done</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, that's what I did, but only works well when they are in sequence. In my case (I've just attached the screen capture in my post) the #REF! is all over the place. So it's really inefficient to do this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the hundreds of individual cells containing a formula with a single array-comprehension formula, it's almost always possible using one of the newer GSheet functions such as `MAP()`, `LAMBDA()` etc. Post the specific formula(s) if you don't have an idea how to do that.

Comment: there's no complex formula . all the formula only linked to other sheet such as : SETTING!B2 or SETTING!C11 etc. where SETTING is not exist yet , then after I add the SETTING sheet then formula need to be refreshed. But I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: I see, then indeed, if your formulas area all different and spread all over the place, changing them to a single array formula will not help. But from the procedure you described, the answer should be just to copy the Settings first, rename from Copy of Settings back to Settings in NEW MATRIX, and only then copying the Shots.

Comment: Thanks That's what I did but only work if only 1 way link. In my case the link is 2 ways. SETTING has links to SHOTS and also SHOTS has link to SETTING.